# Deploy with Rubber to Amazon VPC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, rubber

I currently use rubber to deploy (create instances, deploy code, run migrations, etc) to EC2 and everything works great.  I need to move my servers to Amazon's VPC to open a VPN connection to my web servers and also to keep the databases on the private network.  I've looked everywhere and it seems that rubber does not support deploying to VPC instance at this time.  I've seen other capistrano gems that support deployment to VPC instances (https://github.com/kryptek/capistrano-getservers) so I think it's possible.  I'd like to continue using rubber for deployment since I spent a lot of time setting it up originally and I'm very happy with it.  Does anyone have suggestions on how to customize the default rubber configuration to deploy (create/destroy instances and deploy code) to VPC instances instead?  I'll create the VPC manually, I just want to create instances and deploy my app into my VPC with rubber.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am running into issues too. Were you able to resolve the issues with VPC? If so, please provide details. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not been able to figure out to create instances and deploy the application inside a VPC yet.  I just set up my VPC last night and will need to work on migrating my servers over within the next few weeks.  I'm still interested in any workarounds or configurations to get this to work.

I might start to use Chef or Puppet for instance creation and Capistrano for application deployment.  That seems like a more popular setup for deployment.  But I don't have any experience with either Chef or Puppet.

Comment: I really want to figure this out as well, has anyone had any luck with this?

Comment: @Braden - I haven't had a chance to convert my deployment over to VPC yet since it hasn't been a mandatory change yet but I am going to in the future.  On the rubber-ec2 google group there are two conversations that have some workaround/solutions:

[Link 1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rubber-ec2/rubber-ec2$20vpc/rubber-ec2/RcaK6SMYCbM/LxFE3w-YZi0J)

[Link 2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rubber-ec2/rubber-ec2$20vpc/rubber-ec2/6Don5RQk-rI/Q29gaZg7J1QJ)

Comment: Why not have a rubber instance inside the VPC? Or have a CI/CD server like jenkins , running inside the VPC, do the rubber deployments for you.